# Чем больше надо вывести, тем дольше виснет sublime text

Tags: windows, sublime-text

У меня в Windows 10 установлен Sublime Text, и при попытке вывести много текста он виснет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание на то сколько времени проходит между переносом курсора на новую строку, и выводом.

UPD: В cmd ничего не подвисает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дело именно в sublime-text и именно на Windows.

Можно ли это исправить?

PS: На Ubuntu всё было нормально.

Comment: В терминале (cmd или powershell, не внутри sublimetext) подвисает?

Comment: @insolor нет...

Comment: Не видел, чтобы был терминал в Sublime Text.

Comment: @PetLinux, нажмите Ctrl+T - увидите.

Comment: @wchistow ааа, вот оно что.

Comment: предполагаю, что в вывод python обрабатывается (форматирование, кодировка, тип и т.д) внутри sublime-text перед тем, как отобразить в терминале, из-за этого подтормаживает.

Comment: @ByteBlunder, притом подтормаживает только на Windows?

Comment: Наверное в *nix скрипт запускается через псевдотерминал, соответственно со стороны скрипта stdout буферизуется построчно, а в винде через пайп (или какой-то его виндовый аналог) и выводится уже целиком, после завершения скрипта. А как это побороть -- к сожалению, понятия не имею (не пишу я там)

Comment: а не через форк/exec?

Comment: Время может уходить на подсветку синтаксиса. Её можно убрать в консоли?

Comment: @insolor кстати в терминале **внутри** sublime-text ничего не подвисает.

Answer (score 0):

Печать в консоль (в любом ЯП) = запись в стандартный поток вывода массива байт. Чем больше массив - тем дольше будет выводить.
Сублайм просто чуть медленнее отображает результат на экране, чем cmd

Comment: А почему же на linux всё ok?